# Example of a group in which the equation $x^2=e$ has more than two solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for an example of a group in which the equation $x^2=e$ has more than two solutions, where $e$ is the identity element.

Groups with **two** solutions are easy to find:

- nonzero reals under multiplication
- cyclic group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ under addition
- more generally, cyclic group of even order

But none of these have more than two solutions.

Comment: @abiessu i cannot think of a point to start.

Comment: @AmanMittal: You could start with trying groups of order${}\leq2$ (not much chance there) then those of order $3,4,5,\ldots$; you will find examples before you get to the cases where there are lots of groups of a given order.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443487/example-where-x2-e-has-more-than-two-solutions-in-a-group

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It won't be worth looking in groups of odd order. The elements of a group that satisfy that equation are of order one (the identity only) or two (the cyclic group generated by one of these has only  and the element itself). As the order of any element must divide the order of the group, if it's odd, all elements have also odd order and there're none of order 2 that satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the group $\;C_2\times C_2\;,\;\;C_2=$ the cyclic group of order two ?

Comment: oh yes, any transposition raised to 2 will be an identity .

Comment: Or, in fact, any product of disjoint transpositions, @AmanMittal

Comment: $D_4$ = Dihedral Group too.

Comment: @blondy how is $D_4$ defined ?

Comment: @Aman : $$D_4=\langle\;s,t\;;\;s^2=t^4=1\;,\;sts=t^3\;\rangle$$

Answer (score 9):

Permutation group $S_n$ has a lot of solutions for such equation. For example, any transposition will work.

Comment: Thanks, i have noted this down !!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider Example:

Suppose $G =D_3$ is the dihedral group of order 6 (gp. of symmetries of an equilateral triangle).Then, as we know, there are exactly three rotations$(R_0,R_{120},R_{240})$ and exactly three reflections ($p_1,p_2,p_3$). Also $R_0=e$ is the identity element and ${R_0}^2=R_0=e,{p_1}^2=e,{p_2}^2=e$ and ${p_3}^2=e$.

Answer (score 0):

In the group of 2x2 invertible matrices, consider the diagonal matrices $\mbox{diag}(1,-1)$,  and $\mbox{diag}(-1,-1)$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Find plenty more by using the inverse of  $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: but that will be just one solution no ?

Comment: that is just 2, we need more than 2 solutions for $x$

Comment: @AmanMittal: edited